# Plaster in contact with hot wires

Tags: bathroom

The house we are working on has an outlet missing the plug in part so it is hot! My mother decided to put plaster right onto the hot wire! At first I didn't really pay attention or think about what she did! However, I'm now feeling like my house is going to go up in flames before we even get to move in due to her actions! What do I do? Is it OK that she did that can I stop worrying or should I call fire department and have them undo her mistake before my house burns?

Answer (score 6):

First off the fire department won't help you until there is a fire. They don't do electrical work.

The circuit breaker that feeds that wire should be shut off until the receptacle is replaced or the problem is corrected. If the receptacle is to be eliminated the wires should be capped off and a blank plate should be put on the box.

If you, or your partner, are not comfortable doing electrical work, you should call an experienced electrician to correct this and any other electrical problems in the house.

Good luck on your project!

Comment: Surprised mom didn't have a shocking experience.

Answer (score 1):

**Mom, you're fired!** Actually, the **only** good thing is that the plaster locked the wires in their position so they wouldn't touch each other. However, you **need** to get them free, **to be legal**, & put Wire Nuts (little orange ones are perfect) on them & a Blank Cover Plate. Or, of course, install an outlet with a proper cover plate.

Since you don't know what Circuit Breaker the outlet box is on, you'll need to turn off the "Main" Circuit Breaker & kill power to everything. **It's important** that you're familiar with this thingy for future emergencies. For example, when Mr. Hannah takes a crack at putting the new outlet in with the power still on...he'll "signal" you when he's ready to have the power turned off.

Then, you can safely chip-out the plaster & wet sponge everything clean...clearly seeing the colors of the wires is very important. However, there's a White wire though, so stop cleaning that one when the Sun **starts** going down. Then, put your Wire Nuts on every wire end, screw-on the Blank Cover Plate (if you have it) & go turn the "Main" Circuit Breaker back on.